# How to get public/private key from cacert.pem

Tags: ssl, python, openssl

i has download cacert.pem from internet, but how to get cacert.key ?

How to get public/private key from cacert.pem ?

Comment: Where did you download this file from?  Why do you think you should be able to get the key?  What do you want this cert/key for?

Comment: "http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", i try to set my nginx configuration, i set key for "ssl_certificate cacert.pem", but what key set for "ssl_certificate_key"

Comment: Uhm, I think you must be very confused.   That isn't a set of keys you can use for your own site.  This is a set of CA certs like what comes pre-installed in your browser, to authenticate that sites have a certificate signed by a valid CA.  **There is no way you could get the private keys associated with those certificates.**

Comment: I don't think you really know what you're trying to do... You can't get the private keys of those certificates and you shouldn't even be able to (that'd be a very, véry bad thing) - why nor consider buying an ssl certificate online?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the initial description, you don't.  The key file is what "secures" the certificate; without it, it can only be referenced.  With it, you can sign other certificates.  Which in turn means you can impersonate, and that would be A Bad Thing(tm).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `openssl` command to work with certificate files.

However there is no private key there. A certificate is a collection of a **public** key together with some other info. Nothing more.

Comment: how to make/get file like file.key from cacert.pem, can i make/get it with openssl

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, and am tempted to throw a delete vote on it.  Maybe you could edit your answer.  I mean, we both know he's not gonna get the private key - maybe you could say that, and explain why a little bit to make your answer better.

Comment: Yeah, we could as well delete the whole question which wouldn't make much of a difference.